# Fluent API Single Relation Model

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am very new to Entity Framework though i have good understanding of C# but i've been a web developer for PHP the last 3 years.

I am trying to relate my **Users** table on my **Department** table. Everytime i run, it only returns null on my **Department** property for my **User** Class

This is my builder

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Users>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(user => user.Department);
            });
        }
```

Department Class

```
[Table("department", Schema = "settings")]
    public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        public long id { get; set; }
        public string department_name { get; set; }
        public string department_code { get; set; }
    }
```

Users Class

```
[Table("users", Schema = "settings")]
    public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        public long id { get; set; }
        public string emp_id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string salt { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string middle_initial { get; set; }
        public string display_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public long proj_id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Department")]
        public long dept_id { get; set; }
        public long job_id { get; set; }
        public byte is_active { get; set; }
        public DateTime? date_approved { get; set; }
        public DateTime? date_created { get; set; }
        public DateTime? birthday { get; set; }

        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }
```

Sample Output

```
    {
        "id": 11,
        "emp_id": "100156",
        "username": null,
        "password": "dvser32Z2CaapKM=",
        "salt": "o6k234RGOfasf=",
        "first_name": "test",
        "last_name": "sample",
        "middle_initial": "M",
        "display_name": "test test",
        "email": null,
        "proj_id": 7,
        "dept_id": 1,
        "job_id": 146,
        "is_active": 1,
        "date_approved": "2018-06-10T13:20:04.513",
        "date_created": "2018-06-07T08:20:34.663",
        "birthday": null,
        "department": null
    }
```

Any help i would really appreciate even not for a specific code but the concept itself behind it. Though it would be best to have it while i am understanding the concept.

Also, does my understanding of relationship is correct that i am having a one-to-one relation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options.

1. As Siege21x suggested use include in your queries.

> _auth.Users.Include(u => u.Department);

2.Use Load() method for loading the related field every time you write a query.

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var user= context.Users
        .Single(b => b.BlogId == 1);

    context.Entry(user)
        .Collection(b => b.Departments)
        .Load();
}
```

3. Use lazy loading. For this install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies  nuget package. Then add following lines to your dbContext class

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);
```

You can get additional information from official [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Comment: As more example is and ways provided, i'll consider this as the best answer. Thanks for the info! I'll be sure to look into those usage!

Answer (score 0):

Just was able to figure out the answer. If anyone out there will be as dumb as me, kindly refer.

So when relationship happens you must specify that you are including the related model. So..

```
_auth.Users.Include(u => u.Department);
```